# How do you configure JSHint options globally in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, jshint

I'd like to turn off particular warnings globally when using Sublime Text 2's JSHint plugin. For instance, "laxcomma".

I tried editing the .jshintrc file in JSHint's Sublime Packages folder, but this did not work.

```
{
  "laxcomma": true
}
```

Adding a project specific .jshintrc file with the same options solves the issue for that particular project, but I would like these options to be global.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I know you can do this if you pipe JSHint through Grunt (in grunt.js), I just can't find a way to do it directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the JSHint docs page:
http://www.jshint.com/docs/

> JSHint will look for this file in the current working directory and, if not found, will move one level up the directory tree all the way up to the filesystem root.

So, technically you could put a `.jshintrc` file at the root level of your filesystem (`/.jshintrc`) and every new project would default to those options. Individual projects could override them as needed.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (Mac OS X, Sublime Text 3). I had to configure Sublime Linter as per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769489/how-to-configure-2-spaces-instead-of-tabs-with-jshint-and-sublime-linter-in-sub

Comment: This worked for me only as high as the web root (so my `Sites` folder on Mac OS X).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's having trouble creating a `.jshintrc` in Windows, you could go to *AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeLinter*, copy `.editorconfig` for example, rename and edit it then place it in your root directory like @philip-walton suggested.

If you edit the file here, you may need to Run your text editor *as administrator*.

If you try to rename the file here, you may need to right-click the file, go to Security, Advanced, change the Owner object name to yourself (PC-Name\User-Name), then also Add yourself to the list of Permissions by selecting the Principal.