# How to configure 2 spaces instead of tabs..WIth jsHint and Sublime Linter in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimelinter

I'm trying to configure sublime linter to allow 2 spaces instead of 4 for tabs..This is my settings in SublimeLinter - Open User Settings...

```
  "linters": {
        "jshint": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "excludes": []

        }
    }
```

I want to add indent: 2 (i think). So i tried

```
  "linters": {
        "jshint": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [ {indent: 4],
            "excludes": []

        }
    }
```

But i am not sure how to insert these options because i get the error trying to parse settings: Expected value in Packages/User/SublimeLinter.sublime-settings:20:28

Answer (score 2):

I assume that line 20 is the `"args"` line, as it's malformed. Try

```json
"linters": {
    "jshint": {
        "@disable": false,
        "args": [ {"indent": 4 } ],
        "excludes": []

    }
}
```

instead. I don't know that it'll make `jshint` do what you want it to do (I'd read [the docs](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) for that), but at least it's valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/).