# Ignore certain errors using SublimeLinter-scss-lint with Sublime TExt

Tags: sass

When using SublimeLinter-scss-lint with my SASS files it throughs up errors for common things like,
indentation should be 2 spaces not 4 spaces, colan after property should be followed by one space etc etc.....how can get sublime to ignore these and just watch out for more important errors??

Comment: [Here][1] you have answer for your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769489/how-to-configure-2-spaces-instead-of-tabs-with-jshint-and-sublime-linter-in-sub

Answer (score 0):

You can disable or configure each linter component of the scss linter plugin for Sublime Text 3. You just need to configure the user settings.

Go to:

```
Sublime Text Menu
    -> Preferences
        -> Package Settings
            -> SublimeLinter
                -> Settings - User
```

By default, this file is stored at the path below, but may not exist if you haven't configured any settings yet.

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/SublimeLinter.sublime-settings`

The basic structure of this file, in terms of linter plugins, is shown below and will vary based on what you have set and what plugins you are already using. (I have removed most of the other settings to focus on what is important for configuring the scss plugin.)

```
{
    "user": {

        ... more settings ...

        "linters": {
            "csslint": {
                ...
            },
            "htmltidy": {
                ...
            },
            "jshint": {
                ...
            },
            "json": {
                ...
            },
            "php": {
                ...
            },
            "scss": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "exclude-linter": "Indentation SpaceAfterPropertyColon",
                "excludes": [],
                "include-linter": ""
            },
            "xmllint": {
                ...
            }
        },

        ... more settings ...

    }
}
```

The important bit that you want is under the "linters" -> "scss" section. You can explicitly list linters in the scss plugin to include or exclude.

[Full list of default SCSS linters](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/blob/master/config/default.yml)

As the configuration is set up above, it should disable both the Indentation and SpaceAfterPropertyColon linters for scss. You can add as many as you want to this list.

[SublimeLinter documentation for the settings file](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/settings.html#user-settings)